# MongoDB -3.x AuthenticationFailed SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed, storedKey mismatch

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication

We are using **Mongo 3.0.3**. As our client .Net driver doesn't support SCRAM-SHA-1 type authentication, had to downgrade the security to MONGODB-CR.
The replicaset successfully connects to client and communication takes place.

Below are the proofs:

```
db.system.version.find()
```

> { "_id" : "authSchema", "currentVersion" : 3 }
>
> { "_id" : "admin.admin_mongo", "user" : "admin_mongo", "db" : "admin",
>   "credentials" : { "MONGODB-CR" : "0c23321a8e8ffc2377a61eb54fccf4a5" },
>   "roles" : [ { "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase", "db" : "admin" }, {
>   "role" : "root", "db" : "admin" } ] }

Recently we implemented Auth-Enabled feature in our *Mongod.conf* file, since then after restarting Replica set, seeing the below error.

> ACCESS   [conn253] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for __system on
>   local from client XXXXXXX ; AuthenticationFailed SCRAM-SHA-1
>   authentication failed, storedKey mismatch

Used OpenSSL method to generate the *keyfile*. It's stored with 600 permission in a place where the user running mongod has access.

I have been searching for the solution to this problem, however none is related to my case.
what feels me nervous  is - in Mongodb documentation it says "Keyfiles use SCRAM-SHA-1 challenge and response authentication mechanism. "

so, if the Keyfiles uses SCRAM-SHA-1 challenge and response, how it's going to work in this case as i have already lowered the authentication mechanism to MONGODB-CR because of the client driver?

And what would be the solution to this problem. Please help.

Thank you,.

Comment: Any suggestions please?